# First image appearing small in size and on top left corner in a viewpager when rotate the device

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

Hi in my application i am using the Viewpager with PagerAdapter. it contains n number of images. but when i rotate the device when viewpager is on first image then the image shift to top left corner and appears very small. please have a look in the attached image.

[image]

code which i am using

> ```
>  public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
>
> private final long SWITCH_TIME_INTERVAL = 5000;
>
> public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
>     super(context);
>     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
> }
>
> public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
>     super(context, attributeSet);
>     postDelayed(mSwither, SWITCH_TIME_INTERVAL);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
>
>     int height = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
>         View child = getChildAt(i);
>         child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
>         int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
>         if (h > height)
>             height = h;
>     }
>
>     heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
>
>     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
> }
>
> /**
>  * this Runnable is use for automatically switching the view pager item.
>  * @author 
>  */
> private Runnable  mSwither = new Runnable() {
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>         if( CustomViewPager.this.getAdapter() != null )
>         {
>             int count = CustomViewPager.this.getCurrentItem();
>
>             if( count ==  (CustomViewPager.this.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) )
>             {
>                 count = 0;
>             }else
>             {
>                 count++;
>             }
>
>             //Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Curent Page  " + count + "");
>             CustomViewPager.this.setCurrentItem(count, true);
>          }
>         CustomViewPager.this.postDelayed(this, SWITCH_TIME_INTERVAL);
>     }
> };
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
>     switch (arg0.getAction()) {
>         case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
>         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
>             postDelayed(mSwither, SWITCH_TIME_INTERVAL);
>             break;
>         default:
>             removeCallbacks(mSwither);
>             break;
>     }
>     return super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
> } }
> ```
>
> //PagerAdapter onInstantiateItem code..
>
> ```
>  @Override
>     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
>
>     mImageFetcher.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.placeholder_tabportrait);
>
>     inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
>             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>     View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment1, container, false);
>
>     description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
>
>     title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_title);
>
>     published = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_data);
>
>     author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
>
>     jumbo_tron_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.jumbo_imgae);
>     TrayItem trayItem = getData(position);
>
>     if (null != trayItem) {
>         if (trayItem.getType() != null) {
>                 if (trayItem.getImages() != null) {
>                            mImageFetcher.loadImage(trayItem.getImages().getWidget(),
> jumbo_tron_image);
>                     }
>             return itemView;
> }
>
>
>
>
>
>
>       //xml code.         
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="500dp"
>             android:background="@color/white">
>
>
>
>
>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/main_container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="300dp"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     >
>
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/jumbo_imgae"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:scaleType="fitXY"
>         android:layout_height="300dp"
>         />
>
> </FrameLayout>
>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="@dimen/container_height"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/main_container">
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:textStyle="bold"
>     android:layout_weight="0.5"
>     android:textColor="@color/black"
>     android:id="@+id/car_title"
>     android:maxLines="2"
>     android:ellipsize="end"
>     android:textSize="20sp"
>     android:text=" "/>
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/iv_add_test1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>         android:paddingTop="10dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/add_icon"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/car_title"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>   <TextView
>       android:id="@+id/date_data"
>       android:layout_width="90dp"
>       android:layout_height="18dp"
>       android:text=""
>       android:textSize="13sp"
>       android:layout_gravity="left"
>       android:gravity="center"
>       android:textColor="@color/white"
>       android:background="@drawable/date_bg"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/author"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text=""
>         android:textSize="15sp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>         android:textColor="@color/black"/>
>
> </LinearLayout>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>
> </RelativeLayout> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: If I am not wrong you are loading the images asynchronously. Maybe this is some cache from your library of choice?

Comment: yes. i am loading the image from server and also from cache.

Comment: which library do you use for the loading of the image?\

Comment: @BorisStrandjev i am using this sample code http://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/project.html

Comment: @BorisStrandjev have you found some issue ? i am stuck at this point,

Comment: is it for educational purposes you use this code? Better use a library purposed for asynchronous image loading and caching. I recommend picasso:http://square.github.io/picasso/ What you are looking at is a sample code and might not be well thought of all special cases, e.g. device rotation

Comment: is this a image caching issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110900/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-nitin-tyagi).